# How do Get Office 2019 Registry DisplayName with "For /f delims" Command line

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-registry

I want to get Office 2019's DisplayName "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 - en-us" and echo it.

I found the cmd command using the powercell command.

```
Powershell /command "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ProPlus2019Volume* | Select-Object DisplayName"

DisplayName
-----------
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 - en-us
```

How to get it using the command line "for" detect?
(You can also use "reg query" instead of powershell.)

Comment: Try `Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName`

Comment: what does `using the command line "for" detect?` mean?

Comment: using command line "for /f tokens=3 delims=."

Comment: @jkSON - ok ... WHY mix bat/cmd with powershell? do it all in PoSh to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presuming that your ACTUAL intent is to get a list of installed app names using a set of patterns for those names, this will do that. it also presumes the apps were installed via the usual methods such as with an MSI file or package management. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$PackageProviderList = @(
    'msi'
    'programs'
    )
$TargetAppList = @(
    'libreoffice*'
    'microsoft visual c*'
    )

$FoundAppList = (Get-Package -ProviderName $PackageProviderList -Name $TargetAppList).Name |
    Sort-Object

$FoundAppList
```

the output on my system at this time ...

```
LibreOffice 7.2 Help Pack (English (United States))
LibreOffice 7.2.2.2
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.30.30704
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x86) - 14.30.30704
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X64 Additional Runtime - 14.30.30704
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X64 Minimum Runtime - 14.30.30704
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X86 Additional Runtime - 14.30.30704
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X86 Minimum Runtime - 14.30.30704
```

what the code does ...

- builds a list of the  desired provider types
  i did not want stuff from `msu`, `nuget`, or `powershellget`.
- builds a list of installed things to look for
  it uses wildcards to avoid having to know the target names in advance.
- runs `Get-Package` to grab a list of matching installations
- grabs the values from`.Name` properties in the result
- sorts the list
- stores that in a $Var
- displays that list on screen

Comment: I need to use the bat/cmd executable. 
I want to check if Office 2019 is installed, save FullName as ECHO and print it.

Comment: @jkSON - then you will need to find out how to do what you want yourself. you have not provided the code you are using ... so no one can help with that invisible code. [*frown*]

Comment: {for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2*" %%a in} 
I found a way to use the command.

Comment: @jkSON - i am glad that you found a workaround for that weird, freaky, bizarre, and utterly peculiar need to use BAT/CAM fr doing a loop ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

```
set Office2019ProductReg="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ProPlus2019Volume - en-us"

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2*" %%a in (`"reg query %Office2019ProductReg% /v DisplayName|find /i "DisplayName""`) do (
set office_ProductName=%%c
```

)